# Android Dialog shows empty pop up

Tags: java, android, arrays, dialog

Basically I am trying to populate an array in strings.xml into dialog in Android. Here is my strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="flavour_choice">
    <item>Banana</item>
    <item>Chocolate</item>
    <item>Mango</item>
    <item>Raspberry</item>
    <item>Strawberry</item>
    <item>Vanila</item>
</string-array>
```

And the codes to populate Dialog:

```
static int FLAVOUR_CHOICE = 1;
static String[] mFlavourArray;
static String flavourSelected;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFlavourArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.flavour_choice);

    tvFlavour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFlavour);
    tvFlavour.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyFlavourDialog dialog = new MyFlavourDialog();
            dialog.setDialogType(FLAVOUR_CHOICE);
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "MyFlavourDialog");
        }
    });
}

public static class MyFlavourDialog extends DialogFragment {
    int dialogType;
    public void setDialogType(int type){
        dialogType = type;
    }
    public Dialog onCreatDialog(Bundle savedInstance){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        if(dialogType == FLAVOUR_CHOICE){
            builder.setTitle("Ice Cream Flavour");
            builder.setItems(R.array.flavour_choice, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                    flavourSelected = mFlavourArray[which];
                }
            });
        }
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

However, when I select on the tvFlavour, an empty Dialog with no title or content popped up. I wonder which parts I missed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled `onCreateDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle("click here")
.setMessage("click meesage .....")
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // do somethig or  call method which u want 
    }
 })
.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // do nothing
    }
 })
.setIcon(android.R.drawable.image1)
 .show();
```